# qt 6.6.0 help document went wrong

Tags: qt

Ubuntu 22.04
At first, I can use qt help documents in qt creator, that means I can search a class name in help mode and I can press F1 in edit mode to get help. But after I upgrade qt to 6.6.0 version, the help document become strange. When I press F1, it always says "No documentation available." Many class cannot find in help mode, such as QList, QDebug and so on. But there are still some contents in help mode, like Qt Quick, and the breadcrumb navigation shows that it belongs to Qt6.5.
So I wonder where are the help documents in my file system. And if the files are removed, how can I download them and add them to the help mode.